# Using ReactJS with npm and its giving following error(Unexpected token)

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, reactjs-native

Any information would be really helpful ,Initially i ran the npm install babel-loader command as well.

I have

> ERROR in ./app-client.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   /Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/app-client.js:

Unexpected token (4:13)

```
  2 | var APP= require('./components/APP');
  3 | 
> 4 | React.render(<APP />,document.getElementById('react-container'));
    |              ^
  5 |
```

> at Parser.pp.raise
>   (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
>       at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:89:8)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:522:12)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:277:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:257:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:188:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:165:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:128:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:1046:16)
>       at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:353:20)
>       at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:316:31)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:287:15)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:257:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:188:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:165:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:128:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:92:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:163:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:529:21)
>       at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:36:8)
>       at Parser.parse (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:129:19)
>       at parse (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:47:47)
>       at File.parse (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:517:34)
>       at File.parseCode (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:603:20)
>       at /Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:49:12
>       at File.wrap (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:563:16)
>       at Pipeline.transform (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:47:17)
>       at transpile (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
>       at Object.module.exports (/Users/dawatramani/ReactNodejs/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:88:12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with current versions of `reactJS` you shouldn't use `React.render()` but rather use `ReactDOM.render()` and `import ReactDOM from "react-dom"`. I think this will solve your problem.

```
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentName />,document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

This is a very recent change introduced with 0.14. React is now split into a core library and the DOM adapter. Rendering is now done via ReactDOM.render.

[**DOCS**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :) The issue got resolved by using ReactDOM.render() instead of React.render().

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot paste a Component in render method :)

```
React.render(,document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Comment: use ReactDOM.render instead React.render